# Why is BTC transfer on coinbase taking 30+ hours?

Tags: coinbase.com, coinbase-transaction

I'm really frustrated from the really bad service of coinbase.com.
I'm waiting for a transfer of 0.14 BTC for 30+ hours which is ridiculous! Customer support is totally missing, service is really bad. I bet that once the market goes up, the transfer will  be suddenly completed. WHY THEN?

What is taking you so long to complete a simple transaction for 30+ hours?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they're not a real Bitcoin wallet, I guess they're sending it manually after they confirm it.

A real Bitcoin wallet is a wallet that gives you the full access to your coins and they are just managing your wallet controls and usually its called non-custodial bitcoin wallet, unlike Coinbase.

Comment: That's pretty poor service and product on coinbase side. Once i get my BTC out of them i will deactivate my account. They are really bad. I've missed the buying window because of their sh*t service.

Comment: Yeah, verifying my account took 4 months and they were not responding to my emails. their service is really bad.

Comment: so what's the better alternative?

Comment: I would suggest blockchain.info regardless poor wallet service they provide but it's a non-custodial wallet and secure.